# How do I trouble shoot why my Google Cloud Micro Instance IP isn't reachable any longer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

The IP was fully reachable yesterday, but not this morning.

It isn't a billing issue, and I have restarted the VM - but as I am new to Google Cloud and the tools and menus are exhaustive, I am not sure where to begin

Any tips are appreciated

Comment: This question has been asked many times and there are good answers with steps. There are also articles on the Internet. The most common problem is that your VM is setup with ephemeral IP addresses and the IP address has changed. Another common problem is that your VM disk ran out of space and is failing to startup. Use the "serial port" to view the system startup logs.

Answer (score 0):

As John said, your issue is because ephemeral IP addresses change once everyday.
Please read the documentation about [Reserving a static external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#ipassign).

You could even reach the Virtual Machine with different IP in the main [console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance).